# DataFrame.loc[] Sintaxe - PANDAS - PYTHON - DÚVIDA

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou em um projeto pessoal onde quero otimizar alguns relatórios da empresa com PANDAS.

Em uma das planilhas eu uso o SE, que de acordo com o valor de uma coluna me devolve o nome determinado.

Chegando neste mesmo ponto usando PANDAS me deparei com uma situação na qual não consigo sair do lugar.

Abaixo o script usado:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.read_csv('TLV_PRE_CTRL_ATN_1610_1138997_bau.txt', encoding='iso-8859-1', sep="|")
f_2 = pd.read_csv('TLV_PRE_CTRL_ATN_1610_1139010_bau.txt', encoding='iso-8859-1', sep="|")
bau_df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])

#ESCOLHENDO COLUNAS NECESSARIAS
bau_df = bau_df.iloc [:, [0,8,10,21,38,51]]

#CRIANDO UMA NOVA COLUNA BASEADA NA FAIXA DE INVESTIMENTO PARA O PLANO 
bau_df = bau_df.eval('INVESTIMENTO = FIELD_2 - M3M_REC')

#CRIANDO D> DE FAIXA DELTA

bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO <= 5,  'FAIXA_DELTA'] = "Faixa 2 - De R$0,00 Até R$5,00"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO <=10,  'FAIXA_DELTA'] = "Faixa 3 - De R$5,01 Até R$10,00"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO <= 15, 'FAIXA_DELTA'] = "Faixa 4 - De R$10,01 Até R$15,00"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO <= 20, 'FAIXA_DELTA'] = "Faixa 5 - De R$15,01 Até R$20,00"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO <= 25, 'FAIXA_DELTA'] = "Faixa 6 - De R$20,01 Até R$25,00"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO <= 30, 'FAIXA_DELTA'] = "Faixa 7 - De R$25,01 Até R$30,00"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO <= 35, 'FAIXA_DELTA'] = "Faixa 8 - De R$30,01 Até R$35,00"
```

**Após rodar o código, obviamente ele me devolve todas as colunas como faixa 8, já que todos os valores serão menores que 35 e essa é a minha dúvida. como eu poderia fazer essa mudança respeitando apenas as faixas que de fato eu preciso alterar?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Eu demorei para entender o porque ele me devolvia mas de fato, faz sentido já que a última mudança é a faixa 8 e tudo é menor que o valor dela**

**espero que eu tenha sido claro na minha dúvida e desculpe se estou perguntando algo obvio, estou aprendendo a usar o pandas agora**

Answer (score 1):

Umas das possíveis soluções é  utilizar funções como le, ge, between do pandas. Essas funções te ajudam a comparar números em uma faixa de valores.

```
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO.le(5), 'FAIXA DELTA'] = "Faixa 2"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO.between(6, 10), 'FAIXA DELTA'] = "Faixa 3"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO.between(11, 15), 'FAIXA DELTA'] = "Faixa 4"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO.between(16, 20), 'FAIXA DELTA'] = "Faixa 5"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO.between(21, 25), 'FAIXA DELTA'] = "Faixa 6"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO.between(26, 30), 'FAIXA DELTA'] = "Faixa 7"
bau_df.loc[bau_df.INVESTIMENTO.between(31, 35), 'FAIXA DELTA'] = "Faixa 8"
```

Comment: Funcionou exatamente como eu esperava!  Muito obrigado pelo tempo  que dedicou a me responder e me ensinar algo novo! 

Fiz uns testes aqui e deu uma pesquisada sobre as tres formas... me pareceu mais fácil usar o between. 
Vou precisar ajustar apenas uma coisa, as casas decimais, ja que se eu pegar de 6 a 10 e logo depois de 11 a 15, eu perco tudo entre 10.01 a 10.09.

Comment: @DiogenesCosta, imagina... sempre bom ajudar! Se tiver mais dúvidas pode chamar ai. Grande Abraço!!

Comment: @DiogenesCosta, sobre os valores decimais que você citou, as funções aceitam também, então é só você modificar o range. Abraço!!